# How to compare downloaded file in karate?

Tags: karate

I would like to compare the text file, however the API is returning application/octet-stream which I cannot change currently. That's why karate probably tries to compare the binary and test. That means this:

```
    Given path '/download/testing/'+fileId
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response == read('../files/test.txt')
```

leads to:

```
match failed: EQUALS
$ | data types don't match (LIST:STRING)
  [116,101,115,116,105,110,103]
  'testing'
```

The file test.txt contains just `testing`. I cannot find the way how to convert string to byte array.   I could use probably java function, but at first I would like to find out if there is some built-in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do type conversions: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

So this will convert a binary response into text:

```
* string response = response
```

That should get you going. The reverse is also possible.

For completeness, note that the `responseBytes` variable will always contain a copy of the `response`, but as a byte-array.